# CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version - OpenCV - GPU Toolkit

Tags: nvidia, opencv3.1

I am trying to run the CUDA GPU Toolkit 7.5 built with OpenCV 3.1.0 .

My graphic card is : Nvidia Quadro FX 5800 . Driver version : 341.92 (Latest available version for the same)

Nvidia classifies my Graphics card in the legacy category with the 1.3 compute capability.

I keep getting the error in the title. and can understand the driver mismatch.

I updated to the latest driver for the graphics card.

My question is what version of the GPU toolkit should i build opencv with ? that would also be compatible with VS 2013 C++ env. I tried building it with CUDA toolkit 6.0 and its not compatible with VS 2013.

Sticky situation any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by building OpenCV with 1.3 compute capability. Dont let Cmake choose it automatically. CUDA_ARCH_PTX was set to 1.3 ->(which is the compute capability of my legacy graphics card).